# Find largest value with text streaming

Tags: if-statement, streaming, prolog, text-files, dcg

I need the program that can be recognize the largest value in text.
First streaming a text file in it and

I get the infos char by char but cannot do the calculation and result wheter it is square or not.. If it is square it give the number in sample.txt's coordinates.

```
    setup:-process('sample.txt').
process(File) :-
        open(File, read, In),
        get_char(In, Char1),
        process_stream(Char1, In),
        close(In).

process_stream(end_of_file, _) :- !.
process_stream(Char, In) :-
        get_char(In, Char2),
        look(Char,Char2), 
        process_stream(Char2, In).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Prolog the easier to use input analysis tool is an extension called [DCG](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%274.12%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/DCG.html%27%29%29) (Definite Clause Grammar). It's available in almost any system, thanks to its simplicity.

Using that facility, the builtin [read_line_to_codes](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=read_line_to_codes/2) and the utility [integer](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/swi/library/http/dcg_basics.pl)//1 we can write:

```
:- [library(readutil),
    library(http/dcg_basics)].

setup :- process('sample.txt').

process(File) :-
    open(File, read, Stream),
    repeat,
    read_line_to_codes(Stream, Codes),
    (   Codes == end_of_file
    ->  close(Stream), !
    ;   phrase(check_rectangle, Codes, _), fail
    ).

% just print when |X2-X1|=|Y2-Y1|, fails on each other record
check_rectangle -->
    integer(X1), ",", integer(X2), ",",
    integer(Y1), ",", integer(Y2),
    {   abs(X2-X1) =:= abs(Y2-Y1)
        ->  writeln(found(X1,Y1,X2,Y2))
    }.
```

The output (I've added a scaled up rectangle just to test):

```
?- setup.
found(10,30,20,40)
found(100,300,200,400)
true.
```

Comment: I tried, seems to work: prints **found(-10,-30,-20,-40)** on input **-10,-20,-30,-40   ---square** and **found(-5,10,7,22)** on your sample